# Bootstrap | When should you use <p class="h1"> over <h1>?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, web-frontend

In terms of what Bootstrap provides, I don't see why anyone would use a `p` tag over a `h` tag for creating headers.

```
<h1>Bootstrap</h1>

<p class="h1">Bootstrap</p>
```

The Bootstrap documentation says the following regarding `p` tags:

> .h1 through .h6 classes are also available, for when you want to match the font styling of a heading but cannot use the associated HTML element.

As someone who is new to frontend development, I don't understand the situation *...cannot use the associated HTML element*, if anyone could explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every tag has it's own meaning - [semantic HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics). E.g. [`h1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements):

> Use only one  per page or view. It should concisely describe the overall purpose of the content.

But if you do not want to add any special meaning to your page part, just for it *look like* `<h1>`, then you use CSS to style elements like it.

Answer (score 0):

These classes gives the same *styling* to the elements, but not their HTML properties, meaning that any **scraper**, parser, or search engine indexer won't see it as a header but just a normal paragraph text, which is sometimes the desired output when you need to highlight something to the user visually, but not mark it as a header for the indexers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, HTML labels (h1, p, a, etc) have semanting meaning. This is, they provide information on the element besides some basic styling, and this is key for accessibility (for example when using a screen reader).
Sometimes, you might want to have a text element with h1 aspect (font family, size...) but without such importance from a semantic point of view, that is why Bootstrap offers h1 as a class.
I hope this clarifies your question :)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of semantic HTML and SEO you should use heading tags (h1, h2, h3...), but, if you want to give, for example, H1 appearance to an

element or  without impact on the semantic, you should use heading classes